# I can't spot what needs to be corrected

Tags: grammar, american-english

[image: Help, it asks me to correct these questions but I don't see anything wrong with it?]

I tried to spot errors within these questions, but I can't find any! They all seem like are technically correct?

Comment: Not sure what *do sports* means. The rest is okay.

Comment: 'They all seem like are technically correct?' is ungrammatical.